# Graphing a network in igraph or other packages in R that has each node dependent on covariates?

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I currently have a network in R, available in an adjacency matrix, edgelist, and network format, that I would like to plot based on the covariates of each of the nodes. I have three covariates, `age`, `class`, and `score`, with `age` being 0 or 1, `class` ranging from 1 to 50, and `score` from 0 to 100. I am wondering which packages in R might facilitate plotting nodes and their network edges with node colors depending on `class`, the symbol of a node depending on `age`, and the size of a node dependent on the `score`? Do there exists such methods in `igraph`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `igraph`. Since you do not provide any data, I illustrate with some randomly generated data.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(12)
g = erdos.renyi.game(10,0.33)

V(g)$age   = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE)
V(g)$class = sample(50, 10,   replace=TRUE)
V(g)$score = sample(0:100, 10, replace=TRUE)

plot(g, vertex.shape = c("circle", "square")[V(g)$age + 1],
    vertex.color = rainbow(50)[V(g)$class],
    vertex.size = round(sqrt(V(g)$score+25)),
    vertex.label.dist = 1.5)
```

[image: Variations on Nodes]

## Comments

1. I question that one can distinguish 50 colors to read 50 values of class from the graph.
2. You want the node size to depend on score which goes from 0 to 100. You surely don't want any node of size zero and you surely don't want any node to be 100 times as big as another node. So I used `size = round(sqrt(V(g)$score+25))` to avoid these issues.
3. Because it was hard to read the labels when the nodes were very small, I moved the labels a bit to the side with `vertex.label.dist = 1.5`

Comment: wow this is great! Did not realize igraph could do such things. thanks!